# AttributeError: module 'fiona' has no attribute '_loading'

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

I am new in python and I am trying to work with geopandas library. I have already installed the package using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
```

but when I try to import the library, I get back:
[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCfqI.png)

But searching in my computer directories I have already installed fiona and inside this directory, there is a file "_loading.py"

Isn't it strange that I have both packages installed and I have this error?
Thank you in advance

Comment: looks like you installed your gis packages in your base environment. start over with a fresh environment and install *every single package* from conda-forge (`conda create --name=gis python=3.8 geopandas notebook --channel=conda-forge`)

Comment: Thank you @PaulH !!! it works now but the problem is that I don't have the other packages that i need.. like sklearn etc.. Is there any way to merge all the environments in one so that everything will work fine or i should install again the packages that i need at this environment? To be honest i wouldn't like to have many different environments.. Thank you again!!

Comment: If it helps i present here my environments and  their paths:   

base                  *  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64  

                         C:\Users\george\Anaconda3  
                         C:\Users\george\Anaconda3\envs\gis

Comment: You can add new packages to your "gis" environment, but *make sure they come from conda-forge* (e.g., `conda install scikit-learn --name=gis --channel=conda-forge`)

Comment: I have added in new environment but still get this error. Can you please help? Should I remove this and install fiona again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab, you may just need to [restart the kernel](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html#executing-a-notebook) for the environment.

Answer (score 1):

First, install `python=3.7` then download the related library with the same version of python from here. [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs).
install all of them using `pip`